# Jquery Autocomplete close function

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a Jquery Autocomplete menu with an image at the bottom of it - added with the code below.

Is there a way to have Jquery Autocomplete menu close (disappear) after I click on the picture?

Thank you for your help.

```
<script>
$(function() {
       var availableTags = [
        "new york, ny",
        "new york city, ny",
        "manhattan, ny",
        "queens, ny",
        "brooklyn, ny",
        "bronx, ny",
        "staten island, ny",
        "kings county, ny",
        "richmond county, ny",
        "big apple, ny" 
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ 
        source: availableTags,
        open: function (event, ui) { 
                     var nyc="<img src=\"images/iloveny.jpg\" onclick=\"DoGood()\"/>";
                     $(this).autocomplete("widget").append(nyc); 
            },
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the click event, call `$( "#tags" ).autocomplete( "close" );`.

Here is how I'd do it...

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    open: function(event, ui) {

        var nyc = $("<img />", {
            src: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a3efc8be996c87da020df31e2416151?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
            alt: ""
        });

        nyc.click(function() {
            $(event.target).autocomplete("close");
        });

        $(this).autocomplete("widget").append(nyc);
    }
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7Nph/).

Comment: Actually, have you tested this? I've tried it out, and `ui.autocomplete("close")` doesn't actually close anything.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd No, I haven't.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Thanks, I've modified the code and tested it.

Comment: Alex, please indicate where you've modified the code because Andrew's post shows that it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex - sorry I completely missed the jsFiddle you posted initially.  My menu behaves now exactly as planned. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
function closeAutocomplete() {
    $("#tags").next().hide();
}


$(function() {
       var availableTags = [
        "new york, ny",
        "new york city, ny",
        "manhattan, ny",
        "queens, ny",
        "brooklyn, ny",
        "bronx, ny",
        "staten island, ny",
        "kings county, ny",
        "richmond county, ny",
        "big apple, ny" 
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ 
        source: availableTags,
        open: function (event, ui) { 
                     var nyc="<img id=\"nycImage\" src=\"https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/772597407/DCA_Twitter_normal.png\" />";

                     $(this).autocomplete("widget").append(nyc); 
                     $('#nycImage').click(closeAutocomplete);
            },
    });
}); 



​
```